# Is it possible to enqueue some Sidekiq workers into an external redis queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have a Rails app A with its own sidekiq and redis server. We are in the process of merging another app B into app A. App B also has its own sidekiq and redis server.

As an intermediary step for the merge, I have migrated the Sidekiq workers from app B into app A. But what I want is instead of adding the necessary queues to app A's sidekiq, I would like to send these new workers to app B's redis queue to be processed on app B's sidekiq.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can make multiple versions of the job class which push to different queues, and then pick which one to call at runtime

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to configure app B's queues in app A's sidekiq? I want to enqueue some workers from app A into app B's sidekiq so that B's sidekiq queues can handle the processing from there. I only want app A to be responsible for sending the job to B's sidekiq.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing. You don't "enqueue workers" ... you enqueue jobs. The "workers" are the actual sidekiq servers which run your application. Workers can be configured to read from different redis instances and different queues inside that redis. When you enqueue a job, you send it to a specific redis server and queue. In order for "Job A" to be able to get processed by both "Worker A" and "Worker B", both workers must be running the same app that Job A was enqueued from. Does this help at all?